# Am I injecting context safely? Dagger, Android Studio warning

Tags: android, android-studio, dagger-2

From what I understand reading other answers here and researching, injecting the Application Context into a field should be safe from memory leaks, whereas holding Activity Context in a field would cause a memory leak.

I am injecting Application context with Dagger like so:

AppModule:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideContext(application: Application): Context {
    return application
}
```

ViewModel:

```
// Injected context provided by Dagger
@Inject
lateinit var mContext: Context
```

Android Studio still throws this warning on the injected context field:

> This field leaks a context object

Is it actually leaking a context object, or is Android Studio just not able to determine that its the Application Context that gets injected and I should ignore the warning? Do I need to inject it as a weak reference? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you can't leak the Application context, because the application context is available as long as the Application is alive. (Kind of self explanatory).

Easiest way would be to ignore the warning, it shouldn't get you in trouble.

If you still want to fix the warning, you could inject a WeekReference of the context. (WeekReference). This would probably fix your issue but it would need a null check before each use of the context.

Also, if you are using the Android LiveCycle ViewModel, you should know that you could use the AndroidViewModel (instead of simple ViewModel) that will require a context instance to be passed in the constructor, and you can use that instead of the Application context.

Comment: I was not aware of AndroidViewModel. That is a much simpler solution, tested it out and solves the problem and need for injecting the context. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help :)